# Using a generator vs a normal function for luhn numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, generator

I am new to generators I thought that I could practice writing a generator for a luhn numbers function.
Luhn numbers are valid credit/debit card numbers (no scams, I saw a simple exercise in a book and decided to improve upon it)

I wrote the following code:

```py
from random import randint

def random_n(n):
    range_start = 10 ** (n-1)
    range_end = (10**n) - 1
    return randint(range_start, range_end)

def get_luhn_number():
    while True:
        eight_digit = random_n(16).__str__()
        # *2 of even positioned numbers
        eight_digit = [int(i)*2 if eight_digit.index(i) % 2 == 0 else int(i) for i in eight_digit]
        # turning 2 digit numbers to one digit
        eight_digit = [1+(i-10) if i >= 10 else i for i in eight_digit]
        if sum(eight_digit) % 10 == 0:
            yield eight_digit

f = get_luhn_number()
x = False
while not x:
    x = next(f)

print(x)
```

The printed value is always a Luhn number.

But I just realised that instead of a generator, a simple return function could be used:

```py
from random import randint

def random_n(n):
    range_start = 10 ** (n-1)
    range_end = (10**n) - 1
    return randint(range_start, range_end)

def get_luhn_number():
    while True:
        eight_digit = random_n(16).__str__()
        # *2 of even positioned numbers
        eight_digit = [int(i)*2 if eight_digit.index(i) % 2 == 0 else int(i) for i in eight_digit]
        # turning 2 digit numbers to one digit
        eight_digit = [1+(i-10) if i >= 10 else i for i in eight_digit]
        if sum(eight_digit) % 10 == 0:
            return eight_digit


print(get_luhn_number())
```

And the printed value again is always a luhn number.

Is there a reason why I should use the generator code instead of the function code ?

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

The output I get is a list of 16 numbers, I just did not join them.

Comment: The generator would produce a *stream* of numbers that you could iterate over: `for n in get_luhn_number(): ...`. With `return`, the `while` loop is redundant, because you will always exit the loop on the first iteration, and the return value of the function wouldn't be iterable at all.

Comment: Dunder methods aren't meant to be called explicitly; use `str(random_n(16))` instead.

Comment: is it possible to get N amout of luhn numbers from the generator ? i.e. print 5 luhn numbers from the generator, or any n of luhn numbers ?

Comment: `first_five = list(itertools.islice(get_luhn_number(), 5))`

Comment: Thanks all. I just wanted to see what is the difference between having it as a return and as a generator. This is my first generator and still do not know its full potential.

Answer (score 0):

Generator functions allow you to declare a function that behaves like an iterator, for instance in for loops.

So, if you want to use the get_luhn_number() function as generator, you must use it in that way:

```
for x in get_luhn_number():
    print(x)
```